# pup up html how i can start with click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in the following code to launch ' start a pup up window ,
what I would do instead is throwing it when placing a click on a link but I have no idea how to do , you have ideas ?

CSS3 CODE:

```
<style>
    #pageplugin{display:none;background:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-NsuP8OcOhDM/VH7RiGS6LpI/AAAAAAAAqVk/Itt6IoIgPzQ/s800/sfondo.png);
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:999999;
    }
    #page_plugin_exit{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #pg_plugin{
        background:#fff;
        width:420px;
        height:270px;
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 50px 0 #939393;
        -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 50px 0 #939393;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 50px 0 #939393;
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
        -moz-border-radius:5px;
        border-radius:5px;
        margin:-135px 0 0 -210px;
    }
    #pg_close{
        float:right;
        cursor:pointer;
        background:url(https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-7q7oU2yspzA/VH7T00YAmHI/AAAAAAAAqVw/3J_XdnqBvmY/s56/close.png)repeat;
        height:15px;
        padding:20px;
        position:relative;
        padding-right:40px;
        margin-top:-20px;
        margin-right:-22px;
    }
    .pg_border{
        height:1px;
        width:400px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background:#F3F3F3;
        margin-top:16px;
        position:relative;
        margin-left:20px;
    }
    </style>
```

SCCRIPT CODE:

```
  <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.cookie = function (key, value, options) {
                if (arguments.length > 1 && String(value) !== "[object Object]") {
                    options = jQuery.extend({}, options);
                    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
                        options.expires = -1;
                    }
                    if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                        var days = options.expires,
                        t = options.expires = new Date();
                        t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
                    }
                    value = String(value);
                    return (document.cookie = [
                                                encodeURIComponent(key), '=',
                                                options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
                                                options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '',
                                                options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
                                                options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
                                                options.secure ? '; secure' : ''].join(''));
              }
              options = value || {};
              var result, decode = options.raw ? function (s) {
                  return s;
              } : decodeURIComponent; return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1]) : null;
         };
          (function (d, s, id) { 
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 

                if (d.getElementById(id))
                     return; 
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
          } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            if ($.cookie('popup_user_login') != 'yes') {
                $('#pageplugin').delay(100).fadeIn('medium');
                $('#pg_close, #page_plugin_exit').click(function () {
                    $('#pageplugin').stop().fadeOut('medium')
                })
            }
            $.cookie('popup_user_login', 'yes', { path: '/', expires: 0 })
        });
    </script>
```

HTML CODE

```
   <div id="pageplugin">
    <div id="page_plugin_exit"></div>
    <div id="pg_plugin">
        <div id="pg_close"></div>
        <div class="pg_border"></div>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <div>
         <img src="img/naveicona.png" />
         Name boath
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Simply, you need to open a popup when clicking on a link?

Comment: yes, but how should I do ?

Comment: See the bootstreap modal example http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp